# Unable to connect to Subversion Local repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, netbeans-7

I have installed Subversion 1.8.8 and TortoiseSVN 1.8.5 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit. I have created a local repository at C:/Projects/SVNRepository using TortoiseSVN. While trying to import project from NetBeans i am getting this error.

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/Projects/SVNRepository'
E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '5'; found format '6'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Never use the `file://` protocol. Always run Subversion as a server.

If nothing else, setup `svnserve` as a [Windows service](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking.winservice). It's fast and easy, and doesn't have the problems that using `file://` has.

Netbeans is using its own Java based Subversion client, and it is very likely the client in Netbeans is based on an earlier version of Subversion. It simply not recognizing the new Subversion 1.8 server format. This is another reason not to use `file://`. If you were using a service, you could run any client down to the original Subversion 1.0 version (although you can setup your server to reject any commits from clients older than 1.5 -- and you should).

So, if you're using Subversion, always run it as a service. You can use a package like [VisualSVN](http://visualsvn.com) which will install Apache and allow Subversion to run through that on Windows, or you can follow the directions from above and use `svnserve` as a Windows service.

Comment: Now I am getting this: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E210004: Number is larger than maximum

Comment: So, you're using VisualSVN? Are you doing the checkout via `http://` in Netbeans or `file://`? I haven't used Netbeans. However, if you didn't install the Subversion command line client when you installed TortoiseSVN, you may have problems with JavaHL since it depends upon the SVN C libraries. With Eclipse's SVN plugins, you can use SVNKit which is a pure Java client. Can you do that?

Comment: With VisualSVN i am ruiing subversion as service and using http:// protocol which seems to do for me now.