# How to give local folder file path for Teamcity?, which vcs root have to select?

Tags: svn, path, teamcity, local

Can any one please help me

I have installed TeamCity on my desktop with windows 8.1 OS machine.
I can't figure out how to specify the local folder file path connection, screenshot below. My repository is in `D:/Contracts.Api` folder.

[image: click here for the image]

Thanks and Regards
Vamsi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to Subversion Local repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037641/unable-to-connect-to-subversion-local-repository)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have old version of TeamCity. The versions after 8 support local folders as vcs root url.